# simple MySQL binary data inserting

Tags: c#, mysql, binary

I know how to insert String:

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection();
connection .Open();
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO User ('username') VALUE ('David')");
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

How can I insert binary data using varBinary?

Comment: remove quotes (') from field name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert string as is -

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO User (username) VALUE ('David')");
```

Also, you can insert data as a hex value, use Encoding.GetBytes method to get array of butes, then convert bytes to a hex string (write special function), the result should be like this -

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO User (username) VALUE (0x4461766964)");
```

Comment: What would I do if got 2K of data to insert, this string can be extremely long...

Comment: 2K is not too long. It is important that the size of the packet was not greater than the value of max_allowed_packet - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet